# How to configure php mail in XAMPP

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, email, xampp

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2.  I have installed XAMPP which installed MySQL, PHP, and Apache.  I also installed WordPress.  I have a couple questions that I can't seem to get a straight answer by searching Google.  I've been searching for these answers for over 8 hours.

Questions

1. Is there a way to install an SMTP server to work with Apache? If so, how?
2. Can I configure php mail to work without using SMTP? If so, how?

Problem:

I have configured the mail in WordPress and the sendmail.ini.  I can send a test email and it says it is sent, but I never receive the email.  I really need help getting this fixed.  I'm totally at a loss.

Send Mail output below

```
Test Message Sent

The result was:

bool(true)

The full debugging output is shown below:

object(PHPMailer)#232 (65) {
  ["Priority"]=>
  int(3)
  ["CharSet"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["ContentType"]=>
  string(10) "text/plain"
  ["Encoding"]=>
  string(4) "8bit"
  ["ErrorInfo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["From"]=>
  string(23) "myemail@email.com"
  ["FromName"]=>
  string(12) "Joe Randolph"
  ["Sender"]=>
  string(23) "myemail@email.com"
  ["ReturnPath"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(50) "WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to myemail@email.com"
  ["Body"]=>
  string(68) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin."
  ["AltBody"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MIMEBody":protected]=>
  string(69) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin.
"
  ["MIMEHeader":protected]=>
  string(364) "Date: Wed, 9 Apr 2014 01:55:32 +0000
Return-Path: myemail@email.com
From: Joe Randolph 
Message-ID: <2c046a69376cf33b2ede557c0e3f3e8a@127.0.0.1>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.4 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
"
  ["mailHeader":protected]=>
  string(88) "To: myemail@email.com
Subject: WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to myemail@email.com
"
  ["WordWrap"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Mailer"]=>
  string(4) "mail"
  ["Sendmail"]=>
  string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
  ["UseSendmailOptions"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PluginDir"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ConfirmReadingTo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Hostname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MessageID"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MessageDate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["Port"]=>
  int(25)
  ["Helo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SMTPSecure"]=>
  string(3) "ssl"
  ["SMTPAuth"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["Username"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["AuthType"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Realm"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Workstation"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Timeout"]=>
  int(10)
  ["SMTPDebug"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["Debugoutput"]=>
  string(4) "echo"
  ["SMTPKeepAlive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleTo"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleToArray"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["LE"]=>
  string(1) "
"
  ["DKIM_selector"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_identity"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_passphrase"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_domain"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_private"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["action_function"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Version"]=>
  string(5) "5.2.4"
  ["XMailer"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["smtp":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["to":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) "myemail@email.com"
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["cc":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["bcc":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ReplyTo":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["all_recipients":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["myemail@email.com"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["attachment":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["CustomHeader":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["message_type":protected]=>
  string(5) "plain"
  ["boundary":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(35) "b1_2c046a69376cf33b2ede557c0e3f3e8a"
    [2]=>
    string(35) "b2_2c046a69376cf33b2ede557c0e3f3e8a"
    [3]=>
    string(35) "b3_2c046a69376cf33b2ede557c0e3f3e8a"
  }
  ["language":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count":protected]=>
  int(0)
  ["sign_cert_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_file":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_pass":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["exceptions":protected]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

[image: Email Configuration Screenshot 1]

[image: Email Configuration Screenshot 2]

Below is the code to the sendmail.ini - I'm not sure this was configured correctly

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=mail.localhost.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=myemail@email.com 
auth_password=test1

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=localhost
```

Comment: SMTP and Apache are separate servers, they don't work with each other.  An SMTP server doesn't need to be local either, you can even use SMTP at free emails like Gmail or Yahoo if configured properly. I don't know enough about Windows php to know what mail() uses.  It is more reliable and easier to get through spam filters by using a properly configured SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I understood that SMTP could still be used without a separate SMTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1: Is there a way to install an SMTP server to work with Apache? If so, how?**

As Devon mentioned in your comments, SMTP and Apache are different servers/services and use different protocols all together.  From what I can understand from your question, Yes you can setup the built in SMTP server on your 2008 R2 server and use it to send mail as long as you have a static IP from your ISP where the server resides (if you have a dynamic IP where your server is your IP may be permanently blocked from being able to send to anybody but a local mail server which in your case would be either a exchange server or a 3rd party email application in which would only reside locally for testing purposes).  If you really want to know what is happening to your email I would follow this link on getting your SMTP logs setup and viewing what is really happening to the mail that is sent through PHP.

http://www.vsysad.com/2012/04/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

Also on a side note, if you are using the PHP mail function or any type of mail function (not just PHP) typically you would not use SSL on port 25 unless you configured SMTP to use SMTP over SSL in that manner (The settings you have setup on the plugin does not really make sense).

**Question 2: Can I configure php mail to work without using SMTP? If so, how?**

The plugin you are using has the ability for you to not send to a localhost (Local SMTP server) but rather another address like gmail, yahoo, secureserver (godaddy) or any other mail service provider which would be SMTP for your particular situation.  Depending on the provider the SMTP configuration will change based on the setup that you have for the account.

Here is a brief list of servers that you could use instead of localhost and you would require SMTP authentication (which requires an account with one of them).

http://www.arclab.com/en/amlc/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html

Comment: Thank you so much for addressing my questions individually.  I have another question.  I was told we can set up SMTP on the server itself but that requires installing IIS.  It is my understanding that once I install and enable IIS, it will conflict with Apache and local host will default to IIS.  Is this true and if so is there a way around it?

Comment: This may answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957947/apache-and-iis-7-runing-together