# How to stop XAMPP from interfering with ISS in Windows

Tags: windows, xampp, server

I have recently got internet information services running. But when I start XAMPP, it won't let any programs in the information services folder execute on the browser. E.g. If I had a file named "test.asp", it would redirect to an XAMPP server error page (Even when all of the XAMPP servers are off). Is there any way to completely shut off XAMPP to stop it from interfering with ISS?

Answer (score 1):

it is because XAMPP and IIS are using same port eg.80.i had a similar problem when i was using wamp, I stopped my iis website. stopping iis worked for me. if you want to work on iis dont start XAMPP, if you want to work on XAMPP stop IIS

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that both services listen by default to port 80.
A simple way to fix this is to stop one service and start the other.

**according to XAMPP FAQ's:**

How do I start and stop XAMPP?

The universal control center is the "XAMPP Control Panel" (thanks www.nat32.com). It is started with:

```
\xampp\xampp-control.exe
```

You can also use some batchfiles to start/stop the servers:

```
Apache & MySQL start: \xampp\xampp_start.exe
Apache & MySQL stop: \xampp\xampp_stop.exe
Apache start: \xampp\apache_start.bat
Apache stop: \xampp\apache_stop.bat
MySQL start: \xampp\mysql_start.bat
MySQL stop: \xampp\mysql_stop.bat
Mercury Mailserver start: \xampp\mercury_start.bat
Mercury Mailserver stop: \xampp\mercury_stop.bat
FileZilla Server start: \xampp\filezilla_start.bat
FileZilla Server stop: \xampp\filezilla_stop.bat
```

use the XAMPP control panel or xampp_stop.exe & xampp_start.exe commands, this will stop apache and MySQL service

then run (windows+R) the next command:

```
inetmgr
```

this will open your IIS manager. Select your server and click on "start".

if you want to run XAMPP again, just stop your IIS service from the IIS manager and start your XAMPP using the XAMPP commands.

a better solution would be to have both services running, to achive this you just need to change the port of any of them.

this is a good way of doing it for XAMPP:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15212225/288518